# read.table not detecting delimiters past line 6

Tags: r

I am trying to read a short text file using '£' as a delimiter. It correctly puts the first five lines into two columns, but then gives the error:

*Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 6 did not have 2 elements*

The remaining lines are then all put into the first column. The first few lines of the text file I am reading has the following format:

```
czk11 (4).txt£ 2017-03-20 04:05:07.599+00:00  [F]  Thread 0 System not loaded, loading now, Engine Version: 1.8.11.415
czk11 (4).txt£
czk11 (4).txt£ 2017-03-20 04:05:09.130+00:00  [F]  Thread 0 System loading complete
czk11 (4).txt£ 
czk11 (5).txt£ 2017-03-21 04:57:24.060+00:00  [F]  Thread 0 System not loaded, loading now, Engine Version: 1.8.11.415
czk11 (5).txt£ 
czk11 (5).txt£ 2017-03-21 04:57:25.608+00:00  [F]  Thread 0 System loading complete
```

I am currently using the following lines to read it:

```
dat<-file('merged.txt',encoding='UTF-16LE',open='r')
data<-read.table(dat,sep='£',fill=TRUE,header=FALSE,quote ="")
```

I'm sure there is a simple answer, I just can't see what it is! Many thanks

Comment: What version of R are you using? And what is your OS locale set to? I'm when i try to run your read.table command I get an error that `sep=` must be a one byte value.

Comment: I'm using version 3.2.1 (in RStudio) and my locale is United Kingdom.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
data = read.table("merged.txt",sep='£', fill=TRUE, header=FALSE, quote ="")
```

The output is:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("czk11 (4).txt", 
"czk11 (5).txt"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("", " ", " 2017-03-20 04:05:07.599+00:00  [F]  Thread 0 System not loaded, loading now, Engine Version: 1.8.11.415", 
" 2017-03-20 04:05:09.130+00:00  [F]  Thread 0 System loading complete", 
" 2017-03-21 04:57:24.060+00:00  [F]  Thread 0 System not loaded, loading now, Engine Version: 1.8.11.415", 
" 2017-03-21 04:57:25.608+00:00  [F]  Thread 0 System loading complete"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: If i run that i get a _line n contains embedded nul(s)_ error for every line. If I run it as

`data<-read.table('merged.txt',sep='£',fill=TRUE,header=FALSE,quote ="",fileEncoding = 'UTF-16LE')`
The data is visible again, but same issue as before (stops seeing delimiter after line 5.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what caused it, but it was a problem with the input file- added a skip=7 to the import and it works fine. I guess there's some weird character that it didn't like.

Thanks everyone for the help, good to know i'm not going crazy!